# adding multiple views to linear layout not working correctly

Tags: android

I am currently working on a documentation app for my Library. Now I am implementing multiple Views in a for loop. The problem is, that my second view is not appearing correctly on the screen. My code is down here below:

MainActivity:

```
private void initializeClassLayout() {
int classes = 12;
final LinearLayout classLayout[] = new LinearLayout[classes];
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
String[] allClasses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_all_classes);
String[] classesContentCode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_all_classes_code);
for (int i = 0; i < classes; i++){
    classLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);

    //Set Title
    String currTitle = allClasses[i];
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    title.setTextSize(20f);
    title.setText(currTitle);

    //Set Code
    String currCode = classesContentCode[i];
    TextView code = new TextView(this);
    //String beautifulCode = setCodeSyntax(currCode);
    code.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    code.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    code.setTextSize(13f);
    code.setText(currCode);

    //Set View Specs
    classLayout[i].setLayoutParams(viewParams);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        classLayout[i].setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.classes_background) );
    } else {
        classLayout[i].setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.classes_background));
    }

    classLayout[i].addView(title);
    classLayout[i].addView(code);

    if (i == 0){
        viewParams.setMargins(30, 50, 30, 30);
    } else {
        viewParams.setMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
    }
    classesView.addView(classLayout[i]);
}
}
```

Strings:

```
<string-array name="array_all_classes">
    <item>Buttons</item>
    <item>Textstyles</item>
    <item>Colors</item>
    <item>Backgrounds</item>
    <item>Borders</item>
    <item>Radius</item>
    <item>Sizes</item>
    <item>Transitions</item>
    <item>Filters</item>
    <item>Links</item>
    <item>Navigations</item>
    <item>Loaders</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_all_classes_code">
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button btn-normal-filled-dark">Dark Button Filled</button]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-rtl-dark">Dark Button Right to left</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<button class="button button-dark btn-anim-ltr-dark">Dark Button Left to right</button>]]></item>
</string-array>
```

LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_classes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

The whole thing will appear later like that (Too much space on the second text view):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbBFI.png)

Comment: try adding `classLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` after the creation of the instance.

Comment: @KhalidTaha yes that was the problem. Thank you very much. I forgot about adding the orientation parameters.